# Cannot open a library at FileMapping

Tags: java, android

> Cannot open a library at
>   'FileMapping(from=...\app\src\main\libs\fb2parser.jar,
>   to=C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\27b2f8046309b32ea7a315c7a5d1f140\jetified-fb2parser.jar)'

When I try to import xerceslmpl-2.11.0.jar, here appears other error:

> ERROR: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [file
>   collection] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        implementation project(path: ':fb2parser')
        implementation files('src/main/libs/fb2parser.jar')
        implementation files('src/main/libs/xerces-xercesImpl-2.11.jar')
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    }
```

fb2parser:

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('src/main/libs/xerces-xercesImpl-2.11.jar')
}
```

Comment: have you deleted the jetified xeceslmpl lib from the lib folder directly?

Comment: @Sam. no, there's no this lib in the /libs folder

Comment: Please never post text as an image!

Comment: @csabinho replaced images